# How can I find which columns in a table have null values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table named 'Stack' which has many columns, but I only want to know the columns name which have minimum 1 `null` value.

[image]

The expected output should be the columns name 'Rating' and 'Upvote' as there are at least one `null` value in the columns.

**Output:**
Rating
Upvote

Comment: Please be more specific. Provide an example table with an expected output. It could be something like `SELECT name FROM Stack WHERE value=0`

Comment: @Jakob: The column names and not the column content. Besides `0`and `null` are totally different things.

Comment: Hi Jakob, I have updated my question, hope that would give you some clear picture of my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want in the results 1 row for each column that has at least 1 `NULL` value, use `EXISTS` to check and `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT 'Question_asked' FROM dual WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM stack WHERE Question_asked IS NULL)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Answered' FROM dual WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM stack WHERE Answered IS NULL)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Rating' FROM dual WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM stack WHERE Rating IS NULL)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Upvote' FROM dual WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM stack WHERE Upvote IS NULL)
```

You may remove `FROM dual` if your version of MySql is 8.0+.

I would suggest to get the results in 1 row with `1` for each column that has at least 1 `NULL` value:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM stack WHERE Question_asked IS NULL) Question_asked,
       EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM stack WHERE Answered IS NULL) Answered,
       EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM stack WHERE Rating IS NULL) Rating,
       EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM stack WHERE Upvote IS NULL) Upvote
```

Or:

```
SELECT MAX(Question_asked IS NULL) Question_asked,
       MAX(Answered IS NULL) Answered,
       MAX(Rating IS NULL) Rating,
       MAX(Upvote IS NULL) Upvote
FROM stack
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cf820ed9c3d241546e8ed6333b710444).

Comment: My understanding is that "*...table named 'Stack' which has **many** columns...*" means that the shown structure is just an example.

Comment: @PM77-1 I understand that. Each column must be checked separately.

Comment: @PM77-1 No, still every column must be checked separately. The only difference would be that the column names would be fetched by the system.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this by adaptate to your problem :

```
    delimiter |
create procedure DisplayResult() 
begin
declare v_rate_count int;
declare v_upvote_count int;
select count(rating) into v_rate_count from stack where rating is null;
select count(upvote) into v_upvote_count from stack where updvote is null;

if v_rate_count < v_upvote_count then
    select 'rating' union select 'upvote';
else
    select 'upvote' union select 'rating';
    end if; 
    
end |
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Did you look at the expected output?